# last item in index array not responsive to UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, indexing, uipangesturerecognizer

My swift code below is supposed to add an image view if the function is called. Then when pressed on it should move around. Right now the first time the button is pressed the imageview does not work but if the function is called twice the first imageview moves. If the func is called 3 times the first and second imageviews move but the 3rd one does not. When a imageview is placed on the screen i want it to move immediately

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myArray = [UIImageView]()
    var bt = UIButton()
    var count : Int = 0
    var pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    var ht = -90

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(bt)
        bt.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemOrange
        bt.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 80, y: view.center.y , width: 50, height: 50)
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(add), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func add() { 
        pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.pgGestureMethod(_:)))

        for index in myArray.indices {
            myArray[index].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            myArray[index].addGestureRecognizer(pgGesture)
            myArray[index].tag = index
        }

        myArray.insert(UIImageView(), at: count)

        myArray[count].frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 0, y: view.center.y + CGFloat(ht), width: 50, height: 30)
        myArray.forEach({
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })

        count += 1
        ht += 50  
    }

    @objc func pgGestureMethod(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
        let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + tranistioon.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem but in any case you should put the following line `pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.pgGestureMethod(_:)))`
inside ViewdidLoad rather than inside the add() function.

Comment: Same thing is happening no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Your gesture recognizer handler is updating the `center` of the gesture’s view. Clearly the intent is to add this gesture to the view that you will be dragging.

   So the main problem here is that you’re adding the gesture recognizer to the wrong view. You should be adding it to the teal-colored draggable views, but you’re adding it to the main view.
2. It’s unrelated, but the `add` method is doing a lot of unnecessary stuff. Let’s say you’re adding the 100th new teal subview. Why would you re-update the previous 99 subviews again, too?

   Just configure the view you’re adding and get rid of those unnecessary `for`/`forEach` loops.
3. Again, unrelated, but I’d suggest care when using `center`. This is where the view in question is located within its superview. So, when adding a the button and the teal subview to your view controller’s `view`, you should reference `view.bounds.midX` and `.midY`, not `view.center`. Because the view is taking up the whole screen, you won’t really see the difference, but if the view controller was a child view controller of another view, then there would be a world of difference.

Thus:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // var mySubviews = [UIImageView]()
    var addButton = UIButton()
    var count: Int = 0
    var ht = -90

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(addButton)
        addButton.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapAdd(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        addButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 80, y: view.bounds.midY, width: 50, height: 50)
    }

    @objc func didTapAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let subview = UIImageView()
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(subview)
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 0, y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(ht), width: 50, height: 30)
        subview.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        subview.tag = count

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        count += 1
        ht += 50
        // mySubviews.append(subview)
    }

    @objc func handlePanGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
}
```

A few final observations:

1. I would discourage the use of the `tag`. It’s fine for diagnostic purposes, but that’s about it.
2. In my code snippet, I’ve also commented out the declaration and appending to the array of subviews as it’s entirely unnecessary.
3. Please forgive me, but I’ve renamed the methods and variables.
4. I’m not sure why you’re using `UIImageView`. I’d personally use `UIView` unless you were really planning on eventually adding images at some later date.
5. If you're going to hardcode the button's `frame`, you can't do this in `viewDidLoad` (because the view hasn't been laid out yet). If you're going to set `frame`, you’ll want to do that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You can set up constraints in `viewDidLoad`, but not frames.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, how about you try this instead. This is what I changed: the declaration of pgGestureis now an optional (no need to initialize it twice, which is what you did in your code), moved the initialization of pgGesture to ViewDidLoad instead of it being inside the addFunction (it only needs to be initialized once, instead of being initialized everytime you call the add() function), and finally (and this is the cause of the issue you are seeing), I added the pgGesture to the image before it's inserted (previously you were not assigning panGesture to the image being inserted, but rather to all the other entries of the array).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myArray = [UIImageView]()
    var bt = UIButton()
    var count : Int = 0
    var pgGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?
    var ht = -90

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(bt)
        bt.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemOrange
        bt.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 80, y: view.center.y , width: 50, height: 50)
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(add), for: .touchUpInside)
        pgGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.pgGestureMethod(_:)))

    }

    @objc func add() { 

        for index in myArray.indices {
            myArray[index].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            myArray[index].tag = index
        }

        let imageToInsert = UIImageView()
        imageToInsert.addGestureRecognizer(pgGesture)
        myArray.insert(UIImageView(), at: count)

        myArray[count].frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x - 0, y: view.center.y + CGFloat(ht), width: 50, height: 30)
        myArray.forEach({
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })

        count += 1
        ht += 50  
    }

    @objc func pgGestureMethod(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
        let tranistioon = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + tranistioon.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + tranistioon.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero,in: self.view)    
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a compile error at   imageToInsert.addGestureRecognizer(pgGesture). Stating it must be unwrapped. I put a exclamation point at the end of pgGesture it builds however nothing moves none of the image views move when touch.

Comment: I guess I'm missing some info here. First, make sure, when you test the code you start from scratch with an empty array, otherwise it won't work. Also why are you enabling user interaction? Are you disabling it anywhere and why?